# How to center the horizontal axis

Tags: vega-lite

Is it possible to vertically centered the horizontal axis ? positive values stay on the top of axis, negative the bottom.

I don't find any example like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the `axis.offset` property. For example ([open in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4Ig7glgJgLgFiAXAZgAyoDQjgUwgczhiQEYBWTEKAQxmqVAGccBHAVxwDsBjHBkRnQBOxRJUEB7AA6kATADoA7FkE4ZY+SSzVGSEAA8QAXyNYYQ6p0YAzCUIC2SANqhu1ADbc272n0QCITgAKGhg2e3l9AEoQbV1-RkCg6OMAXSx7aiEAaz13QL4sLm4JKED8fkNEUGsIHHcoPUMzAE8pPxB2SxgIOh6AN0KQan0IeNAJa2tmUQBaRTIsfCFoJGsPZhMsFv5a+saEpJTW9r0uzh6+iEHY4dHxkGXVxHX3Ta2QfrqwfkEhCWyflQJiAA)):

```
{
  "width": 300,
  "height": 150,
  "data": {"sequence": {"start": 0, "stop": 12.7, "step": 0.1, "as": "x"}},
  "transform": [{"calculate": "sin(datum.x)", "as": "sin(x)"}],
  "mark": "line",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "x",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "axis": {"offset": -75, "grid": false}
    },
    "y": {"field": "sin(x)", "type": "quantitative", "axis": {"grid": false}}
  },
  "view": {"stroke": 0}
}
```

[image]